# What is the best option to fill array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Recently I have come to solve some programming problems where I need to fill an array with a default value. I find some approaches but don't know which one is the best option with respect to performance.

For example, if I want to fill an array of size 10 with 0. Here are some options that I ended up with.

**Option One**

```js
let arr = []
arr.length = 10
arr.fill(0)
console.log(arr)
```

**Option Two**

```js
let arr = new Array(10).fill(0)
console.log(arr)
```

**Option Three**

```js
let arr = Array(10).fill(0)
console.log(arr)
```

**Option Four**

```js
function makeNewArray(size, value) {
  let arr = []
  for (let i=1; i<=size; i++)
    arr.push(value)
  return arr
} 

let arr = makeNewArray(10,0)
console.log(arr)
```

I am confused which one is standard to use and needs less time to compile. Or is there any other better approach?

Comment: I'd vote for Option 2 and 3, and among them Option 2. 
Why I chose Option 2 as it creates the Array with new keyword thus keepin `this` context in place. You might not be able to see it in this particular example. But new is useful and should be kept as a practice.

Comment: Well, but as far I know new keyword takes much time and memory. @ZainZafar

Comment: Per the spec (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1) 'Array(...)' is equivalent to 'new Array(...)'. Personal style preference would be for including 'new', as it makes the code intent clearer.

Comment: The `new` keyword doesn't itself "take time and memory" (except insofar as it takes three characters in the program source). It allocates an object, but so does invoking `Array` without a `new`.

Answer (score 4):

If the performance really matters for your use case, [test it](https://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-questions). On my browser, the last is (slightly surprisingly to me) apparently the fastest.

However, all of these can execute millions of times per second (in Chrome on my mid-range laptop), so I'm rather skeptical that this is important to the overall performance of your application. I'd recommend avoiding premature optimization of this sort except in code that you know to be performance-critical. Everywhere else I'd prioritize legibility, so I would write something like `new Array(10).fill(0)` which is concise, likely to be understood by a JavaScript developer, and plenty fast.

The performance difference between that and the last likely has to do with the JS runtime implementation details. (In my case, that's V8, which doesn't optimize Array.prototype.fill using Torque/CSA builtins that can be optimized at the call site, but instead [calls out to C++ code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/797cb87973ec7abb6376738a0455e7d943932c27/src/builtins/builtins-array.cc#246). Likely this is because fill performance hasn't often been an issue in the past.)